# Java - Color recognition program never finds a pixel

Tags: java, image, image-recognition

I'm attempting to make a program which will scan images for certain structures and colors, but my class which recognizes colors is not calculating color RGB elements properly.

My class currently looks like such:

```
  package com.tuskiomi.image;

public class ColorVector {

    public static final int twoPctLeniency = 328965;
    public static final int fivePctLeniency = 855309;
    public static final int tenPctLeniency = 1644825;


    public int x, y;
    public int RGB;
    public int leniency;

    public ColorVector(int x, int y, int RGB){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.RGB = RGB;
        this.leniency = ColorVector.twoPctLeniency;
    }

    public ColorVector(int x, int y, int RGB, int leniency){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.RGB = RGB;
        this.leniency = leniency;
    }

    public static boolean match( ColorVector vec, int rgb){
        int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int b = (rgb >> 0) & 0xFF;
        //System.out.print(rgb);
        //System.out.print("-"+vec.RGB);

        int er = (vec.RGB >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int eg = (vec.RGB >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int eb = (vec.RGB >> 0) & 0xFF;

        int tr = (vec.leniency >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int tg = (vec.leniency >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int tb = (vec.leniency >> 0) & 0xFF;

        int rdiff = Math.abs(r-er);
        int gdiff = Math.abs(g-eg);
        int bdiff = Math.abs(b-eb);
        //System.out.println("-"+rdiff+"-"+gdiff+"-"+bdiff);

        return (rdiff<tr)||(gdiff<tg)||(bdiff<tb);
    }

    public boolean match(int rgb){
        int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int b = (rgb >> 0) & 0xFF;

        System.out.print(rgb);
        System.out.println("-"+this.RGB);

        int er = (this.RGB >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int eg = (this.RGB >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int eb = (this.RGB >> 0) & 0xFF;

        int tr = (this.leniency >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int tg = (this.leniency >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int tb = (this.leniency >> 0) & 0xFF;

        int rdiff = Math.abs(r-er);
        int gdiff = Math.abs(g-eg);
        int bdiff = Math.abs(b-eb);

        return (rdiff<tr)&&(gdiff<tg)&&(bdiff<tb);
    }


}
```

You can see that in my match() function that there are three main numbers that I use. The leniency number, `leniency`, the RGB code that's supposed to be matched to, `RGB`, and the input values `rgb`.

The inner workings of this class is to separate the ints into 8 bit RGB values from the input, `r`, `g`, `b`. There are the expected 8-bit values `er`, `eg`, and `eb, for expected r, expected g, etc. and there are the leniency values`tr`,`tg`,`tb`, for tolerance r, etc.

I subtract the r g b values from the expected r g b values, and if the absolute values are less than the tolerance, than the leniency values, the test passes.

The problem is, when debugging, I get negative values for the input color. This is not the only issue. I put a full rainbow up for the image that I feed it, and even with the ten percent leniency, I will never get a match.

I'm not sure why this is happening, as I source my RGB values directly from BufferedImage.getRGB(int x, int y).

The Javadoc for the function looks like so:

## getRGB

**public int getRGB(int x, int y)**

Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB colorspace. Color conversion takes place if this default model does not match the image ColorModel. There are only 8-bits of precision for each color component in the returned data when using this method. 
An ArrayOutOfBoundsException may be thrown if the coordinates are not in bounds. However, explicit bounds checking is not guaranteed.

**Parameters:**
x - the X coordinate of the pixel from which to get the pixel in the default RGB color model and sRGB color space
y - the Y coordinate of the pixel from which to get the pixel in the default RGB color model and sRGB color spaceReturns:an integer pixel in the default RGB color model and default sRGB colorspace.

I'm not sure why this would turn the integers negative, or break my current recognition code.

I habe seen examples of decoding colours which are very similar to mine. While i haven't tried them out myself,  they look almost identical.

That's all the clues I have, but I'm sure I can dig up more if you tell me where to look.

Comment: I'll make it simple. Look at the code here: alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/getting-rgb-values-for-each-pixel-in-image-using-java-bufferedi

Comment: @HemangRindani That's identical to my code, with the exception that I don't pull the alpha, and also doesn't explain the negative values.

Comment: any other ideas? I'm still stumped

Answer (score 1):

While this is certainly not the whole issue, I found that calling `match()` on a `ColorVector` with it's own `rgb` value returns `false`, since the return boolean condition is only checking `<` instead of `<=`. So:

`return (rdiff<tr)&&(gdiff<tg)&&(bdiff<tb);`

Should be:

`return (rdiff<=tr)&&(gdiff<=tg)&&(bdiff<=tb);`

To cover the edge case where there is no difference between the expected rgb and the actual rgb.

Comment: If there was an edge case, then rdiff would be 0, and it would always be less than tr

Comment: Yes, however when `ColorVector` is created with the first constructor, `leniency` is not explicitly set, therefore `leniency` defaults to 0.